# momentjs - how to respect server date time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm parsing date time received via ajax from server "2014-06-06T10:21:11+00:00"

```
var mom = moment(datetime);             
return mom.format("H:mm");
```

and as a result I'm getting:

```
18:21
```

which is 10:21 converted to my timezone. How can I make momentjs to respect server time zone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That format is not one that Moment.js respects by default (see the [list of supported formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/)). You can however use the [`.utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) method to get the correct result, like this:

```
var mom = moment.utc(datetime);
return mom.format("H:mm");
```

Relevant snippet from the docs:

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.
>
> If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use
>   moment.utc() instead of moment().
>
> This brings us to an interesting feature of Moment.js. UTC mode.
>
> While in UTC mode, all display methods will display in UTC time
>   instead of local time.

Comment: It does work, but I have to update all instances of moment(). Thanks I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need the momentjs version with timezone support: http://momentjs.com/timezone/